# Showing a value from the DB in a blade in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

Within an `<option>` tag, I'm trying to add the selected country from the DB.

```html
<option>
{{ Auth::user()->cpreference()->where('qatype',1)->select('country')->first()}}
</option>
```

The output showing in the dropdown is as below :

```
{"country":"Algeria"}
```

How do I only show the country name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the property on the returned model object

```html
<option>
{{ \Auth::user()->cpreference()->where('qatype', 1)->select('country')->first()->country }}
</option>
```

And having queries on your blade view does not respect separation of concern in MVC architecture

You should add an accessor to your `User` model like this

```php
public function getCountryAttribute()
{
   return $this->cpreference()->where('qatype', 1)->select('country')->first()->country;
}
```

And make a more elegant call in your view

```html
<option>{{ auth()->user()->country }}</option>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Doing this:

```
Auth::user()->cpreference()->where('qatype',1)->select('country')->first()
```

you are getting the whole object, and given the fact that you are trying to output it its being casted to `json`.

To access the value of a specific property just add `->country` at the end:

```
Auth::user()->cpreference()->where('qatype',1)->select('country')->first()->country
```

---

As a side note, I suggest you to avoid making queries in your frontend, you could get the values in your controller and then send them to the view. Also, to avoid this kind of long queries, you could define [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) and [Local Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#local-scopes) in your models. Check the documentation for more info.